# Inserting time into a time column with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

I have run with a problem which i believe is Active Records fault. I am parsing an XML file which contains jobs. This xml file contains nodes which indicate walltime in the time format 00:00:00. I also have a model which will accept these jobs. However, when the time is larger than an actual 24H time, Active record inserts it as NULL. Examples below:

```
INSERT INTO `jobs` (`jobid`, `walltime`) VALUES('71413', 'NULL')

INSERT INTO `jobs` (`jobid`, `walltime`) VALUES('71413', '15:24:10')
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: what is your problem will you please explain in detail?it gives error or something?

Comment: Is `walltime` in your database configured to accept varchar or text? Or is it some magic formatted time type? (If this were my application, I'd store the number of seconds as an integer in the database, and leave formatting it up to the view.)

Comment: On what database do run it? If it's MySQL and the walltime attribute is of Time type, this might be an interesting catch, since MySQL is able to handle elapsed time via Time type and in that case ActiveRecord shoudn't typecast the walltime attribute to NULL.

Comment: Thank you all for your great comments, however, as Milan Novota points out, I am running MySQL and the walltime attribute is of the Time type. So if I run a query directly into MySQL with for example:

INSERT INTO `jobs` (`jobid`, `walltime`) VALUES('71413', '45:24:10')

MySQL will insert this new job with no problem.

Answer (score 5):

The *standard* SQL `time` and `datetime` data types aren't intended to store a duration. Probably in agreement with those standards, [ActiveRecord's time attribute assignment logic](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L190) uses the [time parsing rules of the native Ruby Time class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000305) to reject invalid time of day.

The way to store durations, as you intend, is either:

1. Store the duration as an integer (e.g. "number of seconds"), or
2. Store two (date)times, a start and an end, and use date arithmetic on them.

> ```
> class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
>   ...
>   def duration
>     return start - end
>   end
>
>   def duration=(length)
>     start = Time.now
>     end = start + length
>   end
>   ...
> end
> ```

Comment: This is not the case for MySQl (don't know about other implementations). See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html ("... values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).")

Comment: Hi Milan - yes, MySql may well support duration-storage in a Time column - but because Active Record is intended to be cross-db compatible - it may still "helpfully" interpret the time as a clock-time-only. It therefore would continue nulling out anything that it sees as an "invalid time". Thus the duration option here is probably a better bet for ensuring that it will actually work.

Comment: @Taryn Per our suspicions, I found the code that does exactly that.